# SwiftTaskでのTaskの生成について

Tags: swift, alamofire

SwiftTaskでのTaskの生成の記述方法を教えてください。

あるメソッドAが実行され、その内容が完了後、メソッドBを実行したいと思っています。その際に、SwiftTaskでメソッドAをタスク化して、「.then」または「.success」内でメソッドBを呼び出すようにしているのですが、上手く動きません。（遅延処理でメソッドAの実行を10秒遅らしたところ、先にメソッドB内の処理が行われていることが分かりました。）

ちなみに、各メソッドの内容は、以下です。
メソッドA : TableViewのCellの内容をfor文で配列にセットする
メソッドB : TableViewのreloadData()

SwiftTaskの説明文（https://github.com/ReactKit/SwiftTask）を見てコピペし、Alamofireでの「タスクの生成」、「Alamofireが交信終了後、別のメソッドを実行」することはできました。

ですが、上記のようにAlamofire（URL）との交信をしないBasicなタスクの生成においては、コピペではできませんでした。また、説明文のどこをどのように改変すればいいのかもわかりません。

SwiftTaskのことを本質的に理解しているわけではなく、またそもそも上記の件をSwiftTaskでこなそうとしていることが正しいのかも自信がありません。なので、お門違いな点もあるかとは思いますが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/21285 マルチポスト